# LINQ Generating Bad Query, Error Unknown Column (VB.NET MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq

I'm developing in MVC2 using VB.NET and MySQL and ran into a problem trying to convert a simple SQL query to LINQ.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT Location_Number, sum(Column1) as totalC1, sum(Column2) as totalC2
FROM MyTable 
WHERE year = 2010 and month = 8
GROUP BY Location_Number 
ORDER BY Location_Number
```

LINQ Query:

```
From r In MyTable _
Where r.Year = 2010 And r.Month = 8 _
Group r By LN = r.Location_Number Into l = Group _
Order By LN _
Select New With { _
  .Location_Number = LN, _
  .DepositCount = l.Sum(Function(r) r.Column1), _
  .OtherCount = l.Sum(Function(r) r.Column2) _
}
```

The error generated is:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

The inner exception is:

> Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K1' in 'field list'

Here is the SQL generated by LINQ:

```
SELECT  `Project1`.`Location_Number`,   `Project1`.`C1`,   `Project1`.`C2`  
FROM (
    SELECT  `GroupBy1`.`A1` AS `C1`,   `GroupBy1`.`A2` AS `C2`,   `GroupBy1`.`K1` AS `Location_Number`
    FROM (
            SELECT  Sum(`Column1`) AS `A1`,   Sum(`Column2`) AS `A2`  
            FROM `MyTable` AS `Extent1`  
            WHERE (`Extent1`.`Year` = @p__linq__0) AND (`Extent1`.`Month` = @p__linq__1)   
            GROUP BY   `Extent1`.`Location_Number`
    ) AS `GroupBy1`
) AS `Project1`   
ORDER BY   `Location_Number` ASC
```

Looking at that query its easy to spot whats causing the error.  Simply, the most inner query only returns 2 columns, while the query right above it is trying to SELECT 3, thus the Unknown Column Error.  So why is this happening?  What is wrong with my LINQ query?

Thank you

Comment: Tweaked your title, hope you don't mind.

Comment: not at all, anything that helps me get an answer is appreciated.

Comment: from my brief browsing around this looks like a bug with the mysql connector. I am having the same problem but when i remove the subquery, in my case count, your case sum it works fine. let me know if you figured this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a MySQL connector bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46742

Is not fixed in last (6.3.5) version.

Comment: @Remy, Oracle team hasn't fixed the bug but you can 3rd party provider (for example, DevArt)

Answer (score 2):

Good news! That bug was fixed on 6.3.7 (see comments in http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46742).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a mySQL connector bug.

Try this:

```
Using context = New YourContext()
    Dim sql = "SELECT Location_Number, sum(Column1) as totalC1, sum(Column2) as totalC2 FROM MyTable WHERE year = @YEAR and month = @MONTH GROUP BY Location_Number ORDER BY Location_Number"
    Dim args = New DbParameter()
    {
        New SqlParameter() With {Key .ParameterName = "YEAR", Key .Value = 2010}, New SqlParameter() With {Key .ParameterName = "MONTH", Key .Value = 8}
    }
    Return context.ExecuteStoreQuery(Of MyTable)(sql, args).ToList()
End Using
```