# problem with query to sum two columns

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, sum, grouping

I have this query, a table transaction with value1, value2, and other columns

```
var result = (from t in db.Transaction
group t by t.TransactionId into g
select new
        {
            Value1 = g.Sum(t => t.Value1 ),
            Value2 = g.Sum(t => t.Value2 )
        }).ToList();
```

I am receiving this error: Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K1' in 'field list'.

Any ideas? I am using mysql connector.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ Generating Bad Query, Error Unknown Column (VB.NET MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727623/linq-generating-bad-query-error-unknown-column-vb-net-mysql)

Comment: This solved it for me --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863850/unknown-column-error-using-entity-framework-and-linq

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the field t.TransactionId in the new object that you create.

Even if the query had worked without this field, you would need this field to make the results understandable.