# Unknown column error using Entity Framework and LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I started with EF yesterday and I am in trouble to transform this simple query into EF sintax

Translate:

```
select a.city from offer o, address a, offer_address oa
where o.identifier = oa.offeridentifier 
and a.identifier = oa.addressidentifier
group by a.city
order by count(*) desc
```

Into:

```
var cities = (from o in db.offer
              from a in db.address
              from oa in db.offer_address
              where (o.identifier == oa.offeridentifier
                  && a.identifier == oa.addressidentifier)
              group a by a.city into c
              select new
              {
                  quantity = c.Count(),
                  city = c.Key
              }).OrderByDescending(a => a.quantity).Select(a => a.city);

var cityCollection = new List<string>();
foreach (var city in cities)
    cityCollection.Add(city.ToString());
```

I have tried withou success

```
var cities = (from oa in db.offer_address
                    from of in db.offer.Where(x => x.identifier == oa.identifier)
                    from ad in db.address.Where(y => y.identifier == oa.offeridentifier).AsEnumerable()
                group ad.city by new { ad.city } into g
                select new
                {
                    quantity = g.Count(),
                    city = g.Key
                }).OrderByDescending(a => a.quantity);
```

The problem occurs when try to get inside the first loop!

```
Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K1' in 'field list'`

Line 55: foreach (var city in cities)`
```

With the second case:

`Can't group on 'A1'`

**UPDATE**

This code works, but its not i need

```
var cities = (
                    from of in db.offer
                    from ad in db.address
                    from oa in db.offer_address
                    where (of.identifier == oa.offeridentifier && ad.identifier == oa.addressidentifier)
                group ad.city by new { ad.city } into g
                select new
                {
                    quantity = g.Count()
                }).OrderByDescending(a => a.quantity)
```

Or

```
var cities = (
                    from of in db.offer
                    from ad in db.address
                    from oa in db.offer_address
                    where (of.identifier == oa.offeridentifier && ad.identifier == oa.addressidentifier)
                group ad.city by new { ad.city } into g
                select new
                {
                    city = g.Key
                });
```

Comment: Something like this

`from o in db.offer
                        from a in db.address
                        from oa in db.offer_address
                        where (o.identifier == oa.offeridentifier && a.identifier == oa.addressidentifier)
                        group a by a.city
                            into c
                            orderby c.Key
                            select c.Key`

But i realy don't know how to count(*) with group by

Comment: Is this the very *first* query you tried with your model and database? It's not really a "simple query". What about really, really simple queries? For instance: `(from a in db.address select a.city).ToList()`. Does this work? Due to the fact that the word **column** is mentioned in the exception I'd guess that possibly there is a mismatch between your model properties and the columns in your existing DB your are working with. EF generates a SQL statement and DB says "cannot execute because this column doesn't exist in the table I have" or something...

Comment: @Saluma, this work pretty well `(from o in db.offer
                         from a in db.address
                         from oa in db.offer_address
                         where (o.identifier == oa.offeridentifier && a.identifier == oa.addressidentifier)
                         group a by a.city into c select c.key`, this problem occurs when i add **quantity** that is not a column, its just a **count(*)** i get this exception !

Comment: This code works
`from o in db.offer
                         from a in db.address
                         from oa in db.offer_address
                         where (o.identifier == oa.offeridentifier && a.identifier == oa.addressidentifier)
                         group a by a.city into c
                         orderby c.Key descending
                         select c.Key`

Comment: Gustavo, I have just created three classes as in your example and executed exactly the query in your question. It works without exception. You must show more details: The three classes and also the DB schema for the three corresponding tables. The devil will be in some detail. Generally a query like yours is fine and works.

Comment: `Varchar(45) not null`.

I really don't know what to do

I have tried with `AsNumerable()`

Comment: Without this 2 lines:

`quantity = g.Count()`
`.OrderByDescending(a => a.quantity)`

WORKS =(

Comment: @Gustavo: As already said you must show the model classes and the table schema. It's impossible to help you with the information you give in your question. If the mapping is correct your query **works**. There is no error in your LINQ statement but somewhere else. Please also give information which EF version (4.0 or 4.1?) you are using and which database (SQL Server or...?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update - Try adding `AsEnumerable()` after the first select

```
var query = (from o in db.offer
            from a in db.address
            from oa in db.offer_address
            where (o.identifier == oa.offeridentifier && a.identifier == oa.addressidentifier)
            group a by a.city into c
            select new
            {
               quantity = c.Count(),
               city = c.Key
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.quantity)
            .Select(a => a.city);
```

Comment: Aducci, i couldn't expected that was so easy and simple to build!

Thanks for teach me :)

Comment: Aducci, what about a change a little bit... I just need c.Key to return without quantity BUT i need to order by c.Count() so a made this `from o in db.offer
                        from a in db.address
                        from oa in db.offer_address
                        where (o.identifier == oa.offeridentifier && a.identifier == oa.addressidentifier)
                        group a by a.city into c
                        orderby c.Count() descending
                        select c.Key` unfortunaly i get `Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K1' in 'field list'`

Could you help me?

Comment: I appreciate your quick response, and I still get the same error and try `foreach (var city in cities)` or I'm not allowed to do such thing?

Comment: @Gustavo - Can you edit your question to show the whole linq query and foreach statement