# Unknown column 'Project1.ID' in 'where clause'

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following Tables

```
+--------+     +---------+     +---------+
| Class  |1   N| Student |1   N|  Test   |
+--------+<--->+---------+<--->+---------+
|ClassID |     |ClassID  |     |TestID   |
|Desc    |     |StudentID|     |StudentID|
+--------+     |Name     |     |Name     |
               +---------+     |Score    |
                               +---------+
```

and I need to determine the total score of the **first** student of a class. there can be one, multiple or none existing tests for this student

So the result should look like

```
ClassDesc | StudentName | ScoreCount
----------+-------------+-----------
C1        | Max         |        201
C2        | Tom         |       null
```

I have the following code

```
using (myEntities ctx = new myEntities())
{
var Reslut = ctx.Class
        .Select(x => new 
        {
        ClassDesc = x.Desc,
        StudentName = x.Student.FirstOrDefault().Name,
        ScoreCount = x.Student.FirstOrDefault().Test.Sum(t => t.Score) //Error here
        }).ToList();
}
```

but it gives me the error

> Unknown column 'Project1.ClassID' in 'where clause'

Comment: Nice tabs, +1. Could you include your classes definitions?

Comment: I *knew* it was you. Thanks. Did you looked at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863850/unknown-column-error-using-entity-framework-and-linq) ?

Comment: Are you sure you need Includes if you returning new anonymouse object?

Comment: i fetched the sql statement into a string and... entity framework is creating a invalid select. framework-bug?

Comment: what invalid select-statement is the ef building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var result = (from cls in ctx.Class
                           join stdt in ctx.Student on cls.ClassID equals stdt.ClassID                             
                           select new
                           {
                                  ClassDesc = cls.Desc,
                                  StudentName = stdt.Name,
                                  ScoreCount = stdt.Test.Sum(t => t.Score)
                           }).ToList();
```

Which should generate SQL similar to the following:

```
SELECT   
    Class.ClassID,   
    Class.[Desc],  
    Student.Name,  
    (  
       SELECT  
            SUM(Test.Score)  
            FROM dbo.Test  
            WHERE Student.StudentID = Test.StudentID  
    ) AS ScoreSum  
    FROM  dbo.Class  
    INNER JOIN dbo.Student ON Class.ClassID = Student.ClassID
```

Comment: ok that's not the solution but a good workaround - i added a restriction because classes should no be displayed multiple times